# Why is google sheet converting my percentile to a float?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

Basically I have a cell that returns a percentile - say 48% - but when I make a call to that cell returning 58% in another cell, it returns 0,577380952380952. Can anybody explain to me why? I've of course checked formatting option, tried formulas such as TO_PERCENT() etc.
Why in the first place is google reading it as a float is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting a number doesn't change the underlying number; it only changes how you *see* the number.

If you want a number to "transport" without a floating decimal, you need to apply ROUND to the initial instance/formula, e.g.:

`=ROUND(*initial formula*, 2)`

Note: depending on your locale, the comma above may need to be exchanged for a semicolon.

Comment: So I found a way to round up the source, however in my text where I put A2 &" string..." it still shows 0.57 for 58%

Edit: to reiterate, I believe my issue comes from the fact that I'm using A2 & " string..." and not so much on the percentile at the end of the day. Because otherwise it works just fine but I think it has to do with the way google format text & number in the same cell?

Comment: To confirm it, it works perfectly if I don't add text to my cell's call. So if I just put "=A2", it returns 58%.

If I put =A2 &" string" it goes to 0.57.

Comment: If you just put =A2, the formatting of the source cell generally comes along with it. But if you concatenate, then it's no longer a number that can be formatted to "show you a pretty version that you want to see"; so you see the actual number behind the formatting. If you want further help, please share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it, or a sample of it) here, with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link can edit." As it stands, no one here knows what your end goal is, so it's hard to help you with a concrete solution.

Comment: Hey mate, I somehow solved it following your line of thinking. I had to go to the source, ROUND everything, use a special formatting sequence, then used TO_TEXT on the number and it somehow changed to a percentage again.

Comment: "Somehow" isn't the best word when you're working with data. It can come back to bite you. For instance, if you used TO_TEXT on a number that now looks like a percentage, it is not actually a number anymore. It's... text. That means you likely can't do comparisons or math with it anymore. However, it seems you do not want to share your link, so there isn't any more I can add. Hopefully, it does what you want it to in the end.

Comment: It does, it was always about getting that % to show up so I can then import it in ppt variables based on the cell I was trying to convert. :)

Answer (score 0):

> So I found a way to round up the source, however in my text where I put A2 &" string..." it still shows 0.57 for 58% Edit: to reiterate, I believe my issue comes from the fact that I'm using A2 & " string..."

I ran into the same problem on a string and fixed it by embedding the `to_percent` in a `to_text` in the original calculation for %.

Example: In cell A2 put "=to_text(to_percent(58/100)" instead of just "=58/100". Then in the cell containing your string, it should show as % instead of decimal.

Alternatively, you could put the whole formula in one cell:

Example:

```
=to_text(to_percent(58/100))&"
```

This is the percentage" which should produce *"58% is the percentage"*.